# Should we allow updating closed resource questions with additional content to turn it into a repository?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Yesterday I came across this question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182776/2d-game-making-where-can-someone-get-free-tilesets-sprites

If you look at [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2182776/revisions), a user suggested another link to be added to the question, which was accepted. I can only assume this edit happened because the question is (rightfully) closed and no new answers can be added. I rolled it back thinking that that's not how you should circumvent the closed status of a post. However, it seems the OP reversed this once again.

**My question is this:** if a post requesting external resources is closed but still around, should we allow for the main question to be used as a general repository? My view is that we shouldn't. It will create an even bigger mess if we do, and we'd ultimately end up with a non-question. But perhaps others view this situation differently?

Comment: Since the question has answers, if anything you'd subvert the closure system by editing information into one of them, not the question.

Comment: "Equally so" @CodyGray? Or are you arguing that editing the question would be proper?

Comment: I'm confused about why you'd edit new stuff into the question when you can just edit one of the answers.

Comment: Myeah, true @CodyGray. Though that admittedly hadn't even occurred to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is a problem we should worry about. The question is closed anyways, and it has no chance to be reopened because it is clearly off-topic. In the future it will most probably be deleted. You can vote to delete to make it happen sooner (I did).

They don't make any real harm by adding more information to the question. Other than making harm to themselves of course, because when the question is deleted, all their "work" will be lost.

Of course the edit should not have been accepted, but robo-reviewers will accept almost anything. That is a different (and very serious) problem.

Editing should not be disabled for on-hold questions. They are meant to be edited.

I'd say don't waste your time on issues like this. Time and deletion will solve this :).

Comment: problem solved!

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: Temporarily it seems @Servy. That question is on its way back.

Comment: @Bart How many undelete votes are needed? 5 like delete votes?

Comment: Good question. I want to say yes, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @Bart Yes, five.

Comment: @Bart Of course you know that the number of delete/undelete votes is dependent on the votes the post has, so it's not globally five, it's just that the undelete votes needed scales too.

Comment: Sure @Servy. What I assumed. I just found some conflicting information, but that is most likely out of date.